# Change a parameter's default value on Web page (Pentaho, Interactive Report)

Tags: report, html, pentaho, interactive

I want to change a parameter's default value on Pentaho interactive reports tool (Plz see the attached pics). 
when a user opens an new Report the default parameter should be:

$(date, MMMM dd, yyyy @ HH:mm) 
instead of
$(report.date, date, MMMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm )

I have no experience in web programming, the value can be changed in each individual report but I want to set the default value

can anyone help?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try $('2016-01-01', MMMM dd, yyyy @ HH:mm);

Change the date in the first param according to your need.